# Fix a Channel for a particular SSID (various APs)

Tags: wireless-networking

I have around 6 routers having the same SSID but on different channels. I want to connect to one particular channel. Is there a way in Win7 or any software to fix the channel for that SSID. (My driver option doesn't have Roaming options :()

Answer (score 0):

The routers decide the channel they're broadcasting on, you can't pick the channel you want to use from the client side.

Having said that, depending on your NIC software's capabilities, you may be able to lock to a "preferred" router/AP (that's using the channel you like) via its MAC address.

Comment: U r right, but how do I lock to preferred router/AP (BSSID) via its MAC; I mean any external software for Win7 ?